# How to match regex starting with \\ in Automa.jl

Tags: julia

I want to match e.g. `\\t` string, with 2 backslashes and one letter after it. With regexps, it can be easily done, but I fail to replicate it with Automa.jl.

This is my code, matcha(data) should return true, but returns false instead.

Occursin returns true as expected, but I want to try out Automa.jl to achieve higher speed of regex.

```
using Automa
import Automa.RegExp: @re_str
dat = raw"\\t"
occursin(r"^\\\\t$", dat)
machine = Automa.compile(re"\\\\t")
context = Automa.CodeGenContext(generator=:goto, checkbounds=false)
@eval function matcha(data)
    $(Automa.generate_init_code(context, machine))
    p_end = p_eof = lastindex(data)
    $(Automa.generate_exec_code(context, machine))
    return cs == 0
end
matcha(dat)
```

I tried different number of backslashes in re, but nothing worked.

I'm using Julia 1.3-rc4, and automa 0.8.0.

Comment: Why are you using Julia 1.3-rc4 when Julia 1.3 is officially out?

Comment: because, honestly, I was too lazy to upgrade. 
I use Julia on 1 pc and 2 servers, and then I have some docker images with it, so I'm waiting for some other update before I'll be upgrading it all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was rewriting same function with different variables around it, trying to use single generated function for several regexes. So `matcha` always worked for the regex with this it was generated last, I was generating same function witch different regexps without realizing it. Works now.